# Facebook Timeline: How do you create an aggregation that groups on a custom property?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, aggregation

I'd like to group up timeline actions on a custom property of "category".

What worked:

- I was able to add a "category" String property to my timeline "object" type
- I also made it required
- I made sure that timeline additions were indeed picking up the new category property.

But now when I go to configure the aggregation, it won't let me group on that "category" property.  The only option it gives me is "item"  - which I can delete, but I can't then select a new group-by property.  Very strange!!  Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only group by things that have URLs (so we can make them a link). So make a "Category" object type instead of making it a string. Then it should be groupable.